# What happens to the Executor FixedThreadPool after execution, as executor does not have a shutdown method?

Tags: java, android, threadpool, executor

if I instantiate an Executor like so:

```
private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

And then execute some code as below:

```
executor.execute(() -> {
                    doSomeThingHere();
                });
```

What happens to the threadpool does it get destroyed after the code executes? Executor does not have any shutdown method? I am experiencing a build up of threads in my application every time I run through the process of the app. This may not be the cause but I want to understand this and rule it out. At the moment every time I want to run code on the background I instantiate a new executor in this way.

Comment: "At the moment every time I want to run code on the background I instantiate a new executor in this way", that is most probably the problem. create just one instead

Comment: Don't assign to an `Executor` field. Use `ExecutorService` which does have a `shutdown` method.

Comment: @Eugene OK thanks so I should create one instantiation and use it throughout my code OK I thought that was possibly the case.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks i can certainly do that and call shutdown after executing my tasks. For now i will do this and see if it helps my issues, I am still interested to know if the threads in the threadpool of an Executor get killed and when?

Comment: In a fixed thread pool, no. They'll be stopped when the executor is shut down.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks I guess we can call that answered then, I will just use ExecutorService instead from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ExecutorService` instead of `Executor` since `newFixedThreadPool()` returns an `ExecutorService` and that has a `shutdown` method.

---

If the executor is created with a `ThreadFactory` that creates daemon threads (see [setDaemon](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean))), and there are no other non-daemon threads running, like the main thread or the EDT, the virtual machine will be terminated (stopping all threads)